# Physical data storage getting from table with its view

Tags: sql-server, view, data-storage

Good day!
Who knows how physically SQL Server works the question:
I have protected table and nobody can give information from it directly, just with its view. But it is important to know, the data, which I get with view, is stored anywhere? I wanted to say, that I get data with view, read it, closed query window, can anybody find these data (maybe they are stored in RAM, pool, or HDD … anywhere?
 Maybe if server crashes/abort, after restart, can anybody find data, which a got with view before server’s crash?

**Addition!**
I select data from server. When data are selected, they send to the client and server delete temp data from smemory and don't store anywere at the server. I think it is true. 
If I select data from server, in selection process server rise exception. Server doesn't delete temp data. Can anybody get these temp data from anywhere and use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A view is just a macro: it has no persistent storage.
- The underlying table data is stored in the MDF file
- Transient copies of the data will be in memory or swap file etc
- Copies of data will reside in backup file

However, for simplicity, there are 2 security aspects: logical/application and physical/infrastructure

The view control logical/application security. You appear to have done this correctly.

Physical/infrastructure security relates to server access, remote desktop access, sysadmin access, or access to physical media (SAN, tapes). This is why server rooms have locks on them in simple terms.